# Two adruino are connected to the raspberry via usb, but one is reconnected during processing code is running

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, usb, raspberrypi, processing-lang

I try to solve this a month..but still problem...

I want to make below led-matrix spectrum.

[Thumbnail image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK3Gi.png)

https://youtu.be/X35HbE7k3DA

**※Environment**

[Device UML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGFwC.png)

One Raspberry pi 3 : 2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-full

Two arduino uno with each matrix shield and 16x32 matrix

One usb Microphone

If i attached two arduino Uno to raspberry pi and try to run Processing code(.pde) , one of them is reattached to raspberry pi.

The other one is still working well..

If i connect these arduinos to windows and running pde file...It works well.
(two matrix are showing spectrum well)

What should I do???
Is this code problem? or raspberry problem?

I really need to solve this...

**I already tried....**

1. Reloaded ino code to both arduino Uno.
   (both arduino has same code)
2. Changed boardrate number 115200 -> other number
   (but it must be 115200 to running well)
3. Add arduino to udev rules like below link.
   https://www.intorobotics.com/how-to-setup-raspberry-pi-to-identify-two-arduino-devices/
4. Cross exchange each matrix and arduino.
5. Try to use arduino mega with same code.

**Here is the arduino code(.ino) and Processing Code(.pde)**
https://github.com/snskreationz/Real-Time-RGB-Matrix-Spectrum-Analyzer

**arduino Uno Matrix Pin number**

```
#define CLK 8
#define LAT 10
#define OE  9
#define A   A0
#define B   A1
#define C   A2
```

**Main processing code**

```
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.*;
import processing.serial.*; 

Serial port1; 
Serial port2;

Minim minim;
AudioInput in;
FFT fft;

int buffer_size = 4096; 
float sample_rate = 200000;

int freq_width = 250; // <-O-> set the frequency range for each band over 400hz. larger bands will have less intensity per band. smaller bands would result in the overall range being limited

//arrays to hold the 64 bands' data
int[] freq_array = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
float[] freq_height = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

void setup()
{
  size(200, 200);

  minim = new Minim(this);
  port1 = new Serial(this, "COM8" , 115200); // <-O-> set baud rate and port for first RGB matrix
// Here can be changed to "/dev/ttyACM0" via Raspberry pi
  //port2 = new Serial(this, "COM5" , 115200); // <-O-> set baud rate and port for second RGB matrix
// Here can be changed to "/dev/ttyACM1" via Raspberry pi

  in = minim.getLineIn(Minim.MONO,buffer_size,sample_rate);

  // create an FFT object that has a time-domain buffer 
  // the same size as line-in's sample buffer
  fft = new FFT(in.bufferSize(), in.sampleRate());
  // Tapered window important for log-domain display
  fft.window(FFT.HAMMING);
}
```

**Here are the kernel logs for Raspebrry pi**

```
Nov 11 00:17:27 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5974.165722] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
Nov 11 00:17:27 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5974.665649] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 9 using dwc_otg
Nov 11 00:17:27 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5974.809539] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0043, bcdDevice= 0.01
Nov 11 00:17:27 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5974.809556] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
Nov 11 00:17:27 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5974.809566] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
Nov 11 00:17:27 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5974.809576] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 55639313932351518040
Nov 11 00:17:27 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5974.810729] cdc_acm 1-1.3:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device ---------------------> connected first arduino
Nov 11 00:17:28 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5975.685661] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 10 using dwc_otg
Nov 11 00:17:28 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5975.829541] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0043, bcdDevice= 0.01
Nov 11 00:17:28 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5975.829558] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
Nov 11 00:17:28 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5975.829569] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
Nov 11 00:17:28 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5975.829578] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 8563431373935121D0B2
Nov 11 00:17:28 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5975.830752] cdc_acm 1-1.2:1.0: ttyACM1: USB ACM device --------------------->  connected second arduino
Nov 11 00:17:33 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5980.405877] Voltage normalised (0x00000000) --------------------->  almost at this time starting processing code
Nov 11 00:17:37 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5985.121964] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 10
Nov 11 00:17:37 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5985.122315] cdc_acm 1-1.2:1.0: failed to set dtr/rts
Nov 11 00:17:38 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5985.425669] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using dwc_otg
Nov 11 00:17:38 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5985.569812] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0043, bcdDevice= 0.01
Nov 11 00:17:38 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5985.569831] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
Nov 11 00:17:38 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5985.569843] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
Nov 11 00:17:38 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5985.569853] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 8563431373935121D0B2
Nov 11 00:17:38 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5985.571468] cdc_acm 1-1.2:1.0: ttyACM2: USB ACM device --------------------->  reattached second arduino automatically
Nov 11 00:17:39 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5986.645829] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
Nov 11 00:17:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 5990.805775] Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
```

I really want to run both arduino spectrum via raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Under-voltage detected!` I think it says it all. Rapsberry have many times problem to feed itself from "common power source", not mentioning attached devices. Especially, if you power your LEDs from it too.

You need better power source for Rapsberry (and maybe even power it from pins, but then you need read much more to not damage it) and other powersource for those LEDs.

On normal PC the Power Source is way more powerfull and can feed a LOT of power to each USB.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question!
Your right... it's under-voltage problem..  BOD (brown out detector)...
I given more power to arduino and it works fine:)